# Удаление данных по указателю при уничтожении std::shared_ptr

Tags: указатели, c++

Доброго времени суток!

Разбирал один из видов умных указателей [shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#use_count), и не понял одну вещь: предусмотрены различные варианты конструкторов, например, с указанием того, как удалять указатель, которым владеет экземпляр класса, но при вызове деструктора надо как-то вспомнить, как удалить указатель. Надо в `private` добавить соответствующие члены класса, или имеется ввиду что-то другое?

Comment: зачем вспоминать, как удалять указатель? Вы же можете указать правильную функцию при создании указателя. Она и почистит. Если для какого то указателя нужный особый специальный способ - создайте отдельную функцию. Если же методов удаления много и по факту в процедуру удаления нужно просто передать параметр, то можно воспользоваться методами bind и подобными.

Или уточните вопрос.

Comment: А где вы счетчик храните? Вот там и храните deleter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно вам не нужно указывать кастомный деструктор; если вы пользуетесь перегрузкой

```
template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(Y * p);
```

будет вызван обычный деструктор посредством `delete copy_of_p;`.

Если же вы передаёте кастомный уничтожитель объекта `d`, он (точнее, снова его копия) будет вызвана вместо `delete`: `d(copy_of_p);`. `d` в этом случае либо указатель на функцию, либо структура с оператором `()`, (либо ещё что нибудь подобное), вызов `d(copy_of_p)` должен удалить объект по переданному указателю.

Вы можете, например, передавать пустой уничтожитель:

```
template <typename T>
struct empty_deallocator
{
    void operator () (T* const t) { /* do nothing */ }
};
```

если хотите использовать `shared_ptr` на статический объект или синглтон.

Comment: @VladD это понятно, но как экземпляр класса "вспомнит" о том, какой именно уничтожитель надо вызвать?

Comment: экземпляру класса не нужно помнить уничтожитель. Этим занимается сам умный указатель. Умный указатель - это такой маленький класс, который содержит указатель на собственно объект, счетчик ссылок, указатель на деструктор и тому подобное.

Comment: @aapetrov3: `shared_ptr`? он хранит внутри копию этого самого деаллокатора.

Comment: @VladD тогда понятно, просто в описании это не было указано, спасибо

Comment: @VladD еще возник вопрос: где хранится счетчик ссылок, если он член класса, то у нескольких указателей на один объект будет у каждого по счетчику со значением 1 и смысл умного указателя пропадает, как быть?

Comment: счетчик ссылок храниться внутри умного указателя. Если Вы создали два умных указателя на один и тот же объект... то это уже проблема не умного указателя. Но есть разновидность умного указателя, которая позволяет хранить этот счетчик внутри объекта.

Comment: @KoVadim если так, то когда я удалю один из таких указателей, его деструктор удалит и сам объект, хотя им еще владеют другие указатели

Comment: если два умных указателя указывают на один физический объект и один умный указатель удалить, то да, второго будет битый указатель со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Comment: @aapetrov3: Подождите, всё просто. Вы должны с самого начала иметь один умный указатель на объект. Потом вы его копируете и имеете второй умный указатель. Когда первый умирает, счётчик ссылок уменьшается, и второй указатель всё ещё рабочий, объект жив, зависимости нет.

Просто вы должны всегда ссылаться на объект через умный указатель, и никогда не работать с обычным указателем.

Если вы хотите всё же получить правильный умный указатель по обыкновенному, посмотрите в сторону [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html).